# Верстка диаграммы (горизонтальный вариант)

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте.

Помогите разобраться. Необходимо сделать горизонтальную диаграмму. Вот пример:

[image]

Вот, что делаю я: http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/aFCmC/

Ширина для каждого элемента диаграммы задается индивидуально в процентах %.

Ширина задана, но диаграмма не отображается. В чем проблема?!

Два часа уже голову ломаю...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чего ж тут не понятного? Значения указывайте через точку, а не запятую. Тогда [всё нормально будет](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/aFCmC/3/)